Logic app stand error while completeing msg from topic subscription: VNetPrivatePortsNotConfigured
I've received session messages from the Service Bus topic subscription using SB trigger: When a message is received in a topic subscription (peek-lock). Which doesn't delete the messages after processing. To delete the message from the topic subscription I'm using a connector:
Complete the message with message-id. However, it gives me an error:

{   "code": "ServiceProviderActionFailed",   "message": "The service
provider action failed with error code 'VNetPrivatePortsNotConfigured'
and error message 'Using this service provider action in stateful
workflows requires VNet integration and the site configuration
vnetPrivatePortsCount to be set to a value greater than or equal to
2.'." }

I am looking forward to any suggestions to fix the issue.

To complete message use below design:

And now you need to integrate same vnet for both Logic apps and Service bus as below:
Logic apps:

Service Bus:

In Logic app, In Configuration section-->General Settings-->2 to VNet Private Ports:

Then it will work.
Output:


Thanks for the answer. However, I have need to check with infra support for VNET configuration. Alternatively, I have created an Az Function and it worked perfectly with SB Sessions Enabled messages and completes it without any VNET configuration. Can you explain this behavior, please.. Thanks

For Logic app this is the issue with Completing messages with service bus connector in Standard Plan builtin action connector of service bus.
